# How to convert a java application into java plugin ? whether code remains same or need to be changed?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have written a java programs using JDT in eclipse. I have to convert that to eclipse plugin. My question is, whether my code inside class will remain same? Or do I have to change it for plugin?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't even make sense to talk about "converting" an arbitrary Java program to an eclipse plugin.

The point of an eclipse plugin is to offer functionality that integrates with the rest of the eclipse platform, or uses the features of the platform. Thus, eclipse plugins, by definition, use the eclipse RCP APIs pretty intensively.

If your program's functionality lends itself to integration with the eclipse platform, it could be extended to do so, and if it would benefit from the platform's features it could be ported to use those rather than whatever it was doing before to achieve the same effects. And yes, both would require considerable changes in the program.